# Display text only after reload on firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

i have a special problem that only occurs on firefox. If the site is opened by the first time with firefox, it don't display some text parts in divs.
You can see it here: http://www.cyberassec.de/haftplichtversicherung.php
Look at the bottom or here [screenshot](http://www.cyberassec.de/screenshot_1st_time.png).

After an reload of this site all texts are right displayed. This is reproduceable by cleaning cache. No problems are on IE or Chrome.

I use firefox 38.0.5 on windows 7 professional. The webpage use jQuery 1.11.1 with bootstrap 3.3.4.

Can somebody help to solve the display problem?

Thanx!

Comment: are you using any google fonts?

Comment: couldn't see any difference after page reload.

Comment: same..no issue..i think issue is in your pc only..or describe little bit more if you still facing issue..

Comment: Thanks, problem is solved -- css compressor problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the fonts. Mozilla by default not allow to load fonts from different domains.

You need bit of htaccess code to make it work:

Allow fonts for all domains:

```
 // This will allow font embedding from all domains
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>
```

Allow fonts for specific domain:

```
 // Allow only specific domain for fonts
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://otherdomain.com
    </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>
```

more info: [Webkit Font issue](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2012/03/webkit-issue-for-subdomains/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for your answer!

I found an other issue. I used a css-compressor. It changed "font-size:1.0em" to "font-size:1.0". firefox interpreted this to "font-size:1.0px" and displayed the text in 1px fontsize. After an reload firefox ignore this line, i dont know why? I changed it now to 13px and everything works fine.